# How to keep keyboard and dissmiss after finish with UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, keyboard, uitextfield

I have UIView with few UITextFields. On load I call [textfield becomeFirstResponder] to bring keyboard on the screen. I don't want to dismiss this keyboard until I done with view.

Keyboard dissapear after I "touch" outside any textfield.

I tried to set

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return NO;
}
```

however then I can't dismiss keyboard even after is unloaded.
Any hints how to keep keyboard all the time and dissmiss it just before uiview remove?

Answer (score 0):

When `viewWillDisappear` (or `viewDidDisappear`) is called, then call `resignFirstResponder` on your `UITextField`.

```
    - (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) animated {
          [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Comment: `resignFirstResponder` is the anti-`becomeFirstResponder`

Comment: Not working. First of all there is few textfields so I can't prevent to stop editing them. Second keyboard still dissapear if I tap off the textfield area (any of them), but I want to keep keyboard on the screen.

Comment: Subclassing `UITextView` may be a way to not cede first responder.

Answer (score 0):

call this line before dismiss.

```
view.endEditing(true)
```